# What are these chocolate meringues called?

Tags: chocolate, meringue

I've picked these up at a swiss/ french patisserie and I'd love to try making them myself, but I can't find anything online similar to this.

They are dry and crusty on the outside and have a soft mousse like texture on the inside. They are not chewy or squishy

[image]

Comment: What was the name they were sold under???  "Méringue Chocolatée" ???

Comment: When I make traditional Swiss meringues I don't get that fine crust on the outside and a chocolate mousse like paste on the inside. Maybe I'm getting the timing or the temperature wrong, but the always come either crispy and fully cooked or chewy (even if small) . I'll keep trying

Comment: Getting the desired texture in a meringue based dessert is not easy. I think this is a valid question, and suggestions should go into answers.

Comment: Did you upload a  pic? I can't see but I have connection troubles.  Look for "baci di Alassio" . They are similar to what you have described.

Comment: Yes, there's a pic uploaded. They're not baci di alassio but those look delicious too . I'll probably try making them. I'm  starting to think that if I make French meringues, then freeze them and then cook them I might get something similar as the photo I uploaded

Comment: Meringues au chocolat.

Answer (score 2):

There is [a 'merenguitos' recipe online](https://www.dixiecrystals.com/recipes/merenguitos) and these look pretty much identical.

[image]

> ## Ingredients
>
> - 4 large egg whites without any traces of yolk
> - 1/2 cup Dixie Crystals Extra Fine Granulated Sugar
> - Pinch salt
> - 1/2 cup Dixie Crystals Extra Fine Granulated Sugar
> - 1/2 cup unsweetened coconut
>
> ### DIRECTIONS
>
> 1. Preheat oven to 200°F.
> 2. Line two cookie sheets with parchment paper and set aside.
> 3. Prepare a pastry bag fitted with a large star tip and set aside. (If
>      a pastry bag is not available,  merenguitos can also be spooned onto
>      cookie sheets.)
> 4. Whip egg whites and first listed sugar to very stiff peaks. Add salt
>      and stop whipping.
> 5. Add second listed sugar and gently fold using a rubber spatula until
>      well combined.
> 6. Fill pastry bag with meringue and pipe large rosettes onto cookie
>      sheets. If using a spoon drop two tablespoon amounts onto paper.
> 7. Sprinkle generously with unsweetened coconut. (Sweetened coconut may
>      brown too quickly!)
> 8. Place in oven until merenguitos are very crisp. A good way to
>      determine doneness is to break open a meringue and allow to cool for
>      2 minutes. If the interior feels dry and is not sticky it is done.
>      If not return to oven.

Obviously you would not use coconut and you would adjust this recipe to be more chocolate.